# MySQL: Place rows that have parent_id filled right after the parent id

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns comment_id, comment and parent_comment_id. The query is always limited to 10 and I have to return within those 10 results all comment_id  followed by rows that have parent_comment_id of previous comment_id.

Example: comment_id 2 has answer in comment_id 20 that has parent_comment_id set as 2. I need result to look like this:

```
comment_id ... parent_comment_id
2                0
20               2
3                0
4                0
5                0
15               5
...
```

Is there some nice way to order it? Here is sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70120c/5

Comment: Thank you for providing sample data! Question - your expected result doesn't include `comment_id=1` is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think this query will do what you want. I modified your fiddle slightly to add another comment response to comment 1 (new version [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c965d9/9)). The ordering is a little tricky, the first term orders the comment and its replies together, and then the second term orders the comments within that group (so that 1 and its replies 3 & 15 are sorted in that order). The `DISTINCT` is required to prevent multiple output rows for a comment which has multiple replies.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.comment_id,c.comment,c.parent_comment_id
FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN comments r ON c.comment_id = r.parent_comment_id
ORDER BY IF(c.parent_comment_id=0, c.comment_id, c.parent_comment_id), c.comment_id
LIMIT 10;
```

Output:

```
comment_id  comment                                             parent_comment_id
1           The earth is flat                                   0
3           Response to 1                                       1
15          Another response to 1                               1
2           One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin   0
14          Response to 2                                       2
4           The earth is like a ball.                           0
6           Response to 4                                       4
5           The earth is like a ball.                           0
7           The earth is like a ball.                           0
8           The earth is like a ball.                           0
```